# JFrame : Getting actual content size

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, jpanel

I have created a JFrame, and attempting to get it's size is giving an incorrect result, compared to what I expect.

I have determined that it is including the operating system borders around the edges, and the title bar.

How can I get/set the real size which I have available for rendering?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `JPanel` and not a `JFrame`?  If it's the latter, use `frame.getContentPane().getSize()`.  You may also find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796775/setting-the-size-of-a-contentpane-inside-of-a-jframe) useful...

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah it was a JFrame. I can't beleive I got them mixed up. Apologies, I fixed the question.

Comment: *"it could be because I'm wording this wrongly"*  It is more likely your entire approach is wrong.  It is more common for a custom rendered component to ask 'how big am I?'.  For anything else, the layouts should handle sizing automatically, without the app. ever asking for dimensions or sizes.

Comment: The JPanel inside the JFrame returns 0, 0 as it's size.

Comment: _"The JPanel inside the JFrame returns 0, 0 as it's size."_ Probably the `JFrame` hasn't been made visible yet using `frame.setVisible(true)`.  Before the frame is shown for the first time it returns (0, 0) for its size

Comment: For followers that desire to *set* the real content size (excluding title bar, etc.), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474795/get-the-real-size-of-a-jframe-content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size you are getting is the size of the content *and* the size of the [insets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html). If you use [`Jcomponent.getInsets()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInsets()), you can find the size of the content with simple subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing: JPanels don't have title bars or window borders, they are abstract containers that are INSIDE JFrames.  JFrames are the objects with title bars and window borders.

`JPanel.getSize()` should work as intended.  However, for JFrames you'll want to use `JFrame.getContentPane().getSize()`, because `getContentPane()` returns the `JPanel` (which is the actual content area).