# Get the real size of a JFrame content (NEW)

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a Game in Java, and I don't want to use a layout manager for my JFrame. My class extends JFrame, and looks something like this:

```java
//class field
static JPanel contentPane;

//in the class constructor
this.contentPane = new JPanel();
this.contentPane.setLayout(null);
this.setContentPane(contentPane);
```

I want my `JPanel` be exactly 600x600 px, but when I set the size of my JFrame by calling the `this.setSize(600,600)` method, the `JPanel` size is less than the 600x600 px because the border of the `JFrame` window is included too.

How can I set the size of the JPanel to be exactly 600x600 px?

P.S. I have seen all of the previous post and none of them work for me.
For example:
[Get the real size of a JFrame content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474795/get-the-real-size-of-a-jframe-content) does not work for me.
What else can I do?

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"does not work for me"*?

Comment: for instance when I call 'this.pack();' the frame **only displays** the minimum, maximum (title bar)

Comment: *"I am writing a Game in Java
and because of that, I don't want to use a layout manager for my JFrame."*  Use custom rendering and layouts become irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried setting the min/max size of the JPanel to the size you want?

Comment: when I write 'System.out.println(this.getContentPane().getSize());' I get 'java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]'

Comment: I think what you need is to set the preferred size, and possibly the minimum maximum sizes. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension) and use it on your JPanel contentPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the size of the JPanel to be exactly 600x600 px?

Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom game panel to return the size you want the panel to be.

```
@Override Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(600, 600);
}
```

Then the basic code to create your frame will be:

```
GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now all your game logic will be contained in the GamePanel class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the Frame-Decorations (icon, title, min/max/close-buttons and the border), you can make a Frame undecorated, then it has exactly the size you gave it

```
java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(boolean)
```

Comment: this.setUndecorated(true); failed!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.

Comment: You have to call `setUndecorated` before you make the Frame visible.

Comment: now it works, but is there any other way I can do? the undecorated frame has some disadvantages e.g. you can not MOVE the window any more!