# Why is my JPanel smaller than it should be?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to learn Swing and have made a panel (with help from other StackOverflow code). I added a checkerboard design on a frame, but I have found that the frame is not as big as it should be.

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width = getWidth(), height = getHeight();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i=0;i<=width;i+=50) {
            g.drawLine(0,i,width,i);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=height;i+=50) {
            g.drawLine(i,0,i,height);
        }
        label.setText("H = "+ getHeight() +"  W = "+ getWidth()); // check actual size
        add(label);
    }

    private void gui(Pan window) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();       
        container.add(window);
        frame.setSize(400, 400); // size written here
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

If you run it, you'll see the size of the window. It will be 362 by 384, instead of 400 by 400 as written in the code.

If I change the dimensions to 500 by 500, the window will be 462 by 484.

**Q: Why are the dimensions off by 38 and 16?**

Comment: Java adds insets for the borders. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451252/swing-set-jframe-content-area-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It will be 362 by 384, instead of 400 by 400

Because the size of the frame include the title bar and borders. Don't use the setSize() method.

Instead override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel to return the size that you want the panel to be.

Then you use:

```
frame.pack();
```

Then the size of the frame will be the preferred size of your panel, plus the size of the title bar and borders.

Comment: Overriding `getPrefferedSize()` worked great! Returning a dimension of 400 by 400 makes the window the correct size. However, if I add `setResizable(false)`, it becomes 410 by 410. Thoughts?

Comment: @Chronicle, setResizable() should be done before you pack the frame. The frame is still assuming a Border of 5 pixels for the resizable Border. Since there is not border, the extra space goes to the panel.