# Adding image to JPanel in Eclipse

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jpanel

I have this in my main class:

```
panel.setBackground(Color.green);
ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel("Images/background.png");
panel.add(background);
```

But when I run it I only see the green background and get the exception:

> "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!"

This is the ImagePanel class:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage img;

public ImagePanel(String path) {
    // load the background image
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // paint the background image and scale it to fill the entire space
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
}
```

I'm using Eclipse and this is where my image is: src/Images/background.png

---

Ok, now i have:

```
ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel("src/Images/background.png");
```

and it don't show the exception anymore, but i still don't see the image, only the green background...

Here is the full method:

```
 private void createAndShowGUI() {

        frame = new JFrame("Java 2048 By Xandru");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(panel);

        //Add the background
        ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel("src/Images/background.png");
        panel.add(background);

        //Create the main Frame
        frame.pack();

        //Set dimensions
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //Center it
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((screen.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) /2);
        int y = (int) ((screen.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) /2);
        frame.setLocation(x, y); 

        //Set visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: From a design POV, `public ImagePanel(String path) {` should be `public ImagePanel(Image image) {` (IMO).  That way, the panel can handle an image from file, URL or ..generated in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking an image `2.png` from resources folder

```
Image image= ImageIO.read(new File("resources/2.png"));
```

OR

Try this one if the image is in the same package(folder) where the class is present

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("2.png"));
```

Here is the project structure

[image]

---

-- EDIT-

Try in this way

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java 2048 By Xandru");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Add the background
        ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel("src/images/2.png");
        frame.add(background);

        // Create the main Frame
        frame.pack();

        // Set dimensions
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        // Center it
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Set visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
});
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the right way to call your attention, i'm new on stackoverflow... anyway, i have updated the question :)

Comment: No problem. Its the right way. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the exception, so now i have the image loaded correctly but i still can't get it on screen... :(

Comment: @XandruDavid you should probably show how you are adding the panel

Comment: Don't use `null` layout. Don't use `setBounds`. Why are you using an extra `panel` in between?

Comment: the null layout and the bounds are becouse i want the panel to fill the frame... for the panel... i'll replace the main panel with the ImagePanel...

Comment: use `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` to center it.

Comment: `JFrame` has default `BorderLayour` that add a component in the center by default.

Comment: Always use `EventQueue.invokeLater` in Swing application.

Comment: You can set Look & Feel by calling `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`.

Comment: Use this way to set the size `frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));`

Comment: Ok, thank you all, it warks without the extra panel... Now i have a little problem, the windows is WIDTHxHEIGHT but i wanted the working area to be WIDTHxHEIGHT, how can i do it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Where you have defined HEIGHT, WIDTH? I think its referring to `ImageObserver.HEIGHT` and `ImageObserver.WIDTH` that is 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: I have frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height)); but it sets the dimensions of the entire window (with title, minimize button, maximize button etc)... That's not what I wanted couse my ImagePanel will not be width x height this way...

Comment: Why you want to set it. Just make it a re-sizable window. because height of title bar will be different on different OS and themes.

Comment: Look at this thread [Java Upper Boundary Graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722777/java-upper-boundary-graphics/22722949#22722949) You will get the answer of your new question.

Comment: I've got it... The problem is that i don't want the user to resize it, all i want is a 450x450 image to fill the Frame... and it have to be all times that size, even if i make a borderless frame or a normal frame, how can i do it?

Comment: You want the exact height/width of image then try this in `paintComponent()` method. `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);` or `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 450, 450, this);`

Comment: I've bounded the panel to 450x450 but it goes out of view because window is still 450x450 (with borders and title bar)...

Comment: You want to set the height of image or panel or frame?

Comment: I want to see a 450 by 450 image inside my frame, that's all xD so i have to set frame something like 455 by 475 but this sucks...

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451252/swing-set-jframe-content-area-size) That was it... Worked with the preferredSize method... sorry for my bad english and thank you very much for your help ;)

Comment: Have you tried `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 450, 450, this);` just this one nothing else. no other size of panel or frame.